# Connection to the site is not private on Flask Admin

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, flask, flask-admin

I am getting following on the flask admin hosted on amazon ec2 machine. I used user name and password from configuration file but login is not successful.

Same thing i try on local machine works perfectly fine.
[image]

**This is what i use for authentication**

`def is_accessible(self):
        auth = request.authorization or request.environ.get('REMOTE_USER')  # workaround for Apache
        if not auth or (auth.username, auth.password) != app.config['ADMIN_CREDENTIALS']:
            raise HTTPException('', Response('You have to an administrator.', 401,
                {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="Login Required"'}
            ))

        return True`

Comment: How do you secure flask admin for authentication?

Comment: i just used password authentation

Comment: Just FYI, but you blacked out the URL in the bar, but left it in the screenshot of the dialog